# How to decrease the time required by a PMSM (outer rotor) motor to reach rated speed?

Tags: simulation, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, time-constant, pmsm

I have a Outer rotor PMSM with FOC control and rated speed of 3000 rpm. It takes about **t=0.5 seconds** to reach 3000 rpm without load.

**Goal:**

1. Decrease the **Time "t"**, so that the motor can reach 3000 rpm in (let’s say) 0.2 seconds. The changes can only be made in the Control technique of motor (FOC).
2. Does anybody know if its possible to calculate time required to reach max speed at no load in ANSYS Maxwell or MotorCAD?

Can anybody please give me suggestions?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: well, this is classical control theory: the control is probably designed to not overshoot too much and to achieve exactness and stability at *acceptable* reaction time. The moment you want to be quicker at spinup, you'll need to make compromises on these fronts. Are you willing to do that?

Comment: Hii marcus, thanks for reply. What will be the compromises? And yes i am will to test them if possible? Can you please let me know? Also where can i find the literature about the control theory that you mentioned? Thanks in Advance

Comment: faster reaction can only be bought with more overshoot, and longer oscillation (assuming the original controller wasn't badly designed). The book you want to read is really your arbitrary university's "introduction to control theory" textbook. This is a lecture in all electrical engineering Bachelor studies!

Comment: admittedly, FOC design certainly is more involved, but any textbook on that (not an expert in motor controls myself) would rely on a solid foundation in classical control theory.

Comment: We will need to know more about how this motor is driven. For instance if the controller is current or voltage limited already then no performance gains will be had without an angle grinder.